# Serilog console conditional output template based on log level, (and low profile color in console)

Tags: configure, serilog

Please first excuse me, I am not so familiar with the Serilog, I started with it quite recently.
I would like use a certain log level in my console app to be used as normal console output by default (output just the rendered message) and then optionally, when specified by optional commandline argument like -verb also have output in such default format `"{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"`(and additionally perhaps with more low profile color)

My questions are:

1. which (the cleanest) way can it be accomplished?

   a) in case of filtering: can you please help me, how the filtering would look like in the fluent configuration API?

   b) in case of using a custom ITextFormater, can it somehow inherit the part 
   providing rendering such format templates as mentioned above?

   c) any better way, or ??
2. is it possible to somehow make (using the output format template) for the console sink such a "lower profile" color?

Answer (score 1):

You can just switch the `outputTemplate` based on the presence of the command-line flag:

```
bool verbose = false;
var template = verbose ?
    "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" :
    "{Message}{NewLine}";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: template,
                     theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Grayscale)
    .CreateLogger();
```

See the `theme` argument supplied in the example for how to change coloring.

Comment: Thanks, the theme argument answers the 2). To question 1) please forget about the -verbose command line param - it makes the question a bit more complex) The question stands how to (the most clear way) do a functionality that for LogLevel=Information it produce as there would be {Message}{NewLine}  and for another LogLevel the output like for template  [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception} ? TIA

Comment: For b), a custom `ITextFormatter`, it can create and use `MessageTemplateTextFormatter` under the hood to re-use the Serilog output template mechanism. Just create two `MessageTemplateTextFormatter`s with different templates, and switch between them based on level. HTH!

Comment: Thanks again, now  for the advice using the two MessageTemplateTextFormatters inside of the custom ITexFormater. I was not sure about passing ITextFormater, I just passed null, however it worked quite well. Still unlikely one think in the API might be  be missing - the ability to define different theme (I would like to keep color console output :) TO do it, could it be done by defining own Write.Console static method with theme parameter (or is there other approach)?